# One dimensional string clustering with custom distance - ruby

Tags: ruby, artificial-intelligence, k-means, string-aggregation

I have an array of strings that are names of products from multiple shops. Now, I need o cluster that array to obtain clusters that are containing the same product regardless of the shop that is listed.

As example:

```
data = ["Laptop Asus xd45jkl", 
        "Laptop Acer d3000",
        "Notebooh Hp hxsss", 
        "Laptop Asus xd45jkl intel core i7", 
        "Laptop Acer d3000 intel core i5 4gb RAM"
]
desired_output = [["Laptop Asus xd45jkl", Laptop Asus xd45jkl intel core i7],
          ["Laptop Acer d3000", "Laptop Acer d3000 intel core i5 4gb RAM"]
          [""Notebooh Hp hxsss""]
         ]
```

As distance between product names I thought to JaroWinkler from [amatch gem](https://github.com/flori/amatch). There is an algorithm k-means like or something else that could produce that clustering of this array of strings?

Answer (score 0):

I thought to something like this:

```
data = ["Laptop Asus xd45jkl", "Laptop Acer d3000", "Notebooh Hp hxsss", "Laptop Asus xd45jkl intel core i7", "Laptop Acer d3000 intel core i5 4gb RAM" ]
clusters = Hash.new

data.each do |item|
    brand =  item.split[1]
    clusters[brand] = [] if clusters[brand].nil?
    clusters[brand] << item
end

clusters.map! { |k, v| v }
```

I'm not sure if this is **k-means compliant** and about its performance on large datasets.

**Edit:** it takes about 2sec on 50,000 items.